# Load multiple excel sheets into mysql

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple excel files which inturn have multiple sheets in them I am trying to load them into mysql database
Below is my working code for excel with one sheet

```
import pandas as pd
    df = pd.read_excel(open(path+ "/" +file, 'rb'), sheet_name='Sheet1')
                      table_name = "sample"
                      # Defaulting null values to 0 .
                   df=df.fillna(0)
                 # inserting the data.
                   df.to_sql(con=engine, name=table_name, if_exists='replace', schema=None)
```

The above code works but one problem
1. I am hard coding the table name ideally i would like to have the same name as excel file I can probably use split and just get file name is there a better way to get the file name without extension.

but the real problem is here

Now in my folder there can be multiple excel files with mulyiple sheets inside them
example document1.xlsx(with two sheets inside it sheet1 and sheet2)
This is what I did

```
    xls = pd.ExcelFile('document1.xlsx')
                sheets = []
                sheets = xls.sheet_names
                #type(sheets)
                #print(sheets)this gives me list containing sheet1,sheet2
                for i in sheets:
                    #print(i) 
                    df = pd.read_excel(open(path+ "/" +file, 'rb'), sheet_name=i)
   df.to_sql(con=engine, name=table_name, if_exists='replace', schema=None)
```

In the above code the data frame saves both sheets data but i want to store sheet 1 data first load it into a table then take the second sheet and load it into an another table so in the above df i did this change to see if code is working
pd.read_excel(open(path+ "/" +file, 'rb'), sheet_name=i[0]) but it doesnt work any ideas??

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

This definitely isn't a Python answer, but if you are OK with using a different tool, I'd recommend this.

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/addins/rdbmerge.htm

Use the AddIn, merge all sheets in all files (in a folder) into one master data set.  Then, push that into MySQL, or import it into MySQL using the Workbench.  It would be nice to see Python do this, but if you are in a time crunch and you just want to get this done, try what I'm recommending here.

Comment: Hi thanks for the solution I appreciate the effort. I managed to get this using python pandas and sql alchemy. I dont have the code with me right now but here is the approach. First use pandas Excelfile option to open complete excel next is get the sheet names into a list using sheet_names step 3 would be  use the pandas read_excel and pass the sheetnames to the sheet_name parameter and use df_to_sql pandas function/method(sorry new to python) and load to mysql database. Hope this is clear i will post the code probably in the evening. Again thanks for the effort.

Comment: That makes sense.  It would be great if you could post the final version of your code when you have a chance.  I, for one, would be very curious to see the solution.  I'm pretty sure others would be interested in seeing this as well.  The entire community would benefit from it.

Comment: Also note if the excel is too big or wide then we may have to convert the excel into csv and then load it into mysql database. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@ryguy72
Code looks something like this

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile(path + "/" + file)
                  #Create a list which consists of all sheet names in a Excel file.
                  sheets = []# declaring empty list
                  sheets = xls.sheet_names # getting sheet names
                  ex_op = open(path +"/" + file, 'rb')# opening the Excel sheets
                  for i in sheets:
                      # Passing the sheet names as table names.
                      table_name = i
                      #read that sheet that is being processed
                      df = pd.read_excel(ex_op, sheet_name=i)
                      # Defaulting null values to 0 to be confirmed.
                      df=df.fillna(0)
                      #Droping and recreating the table and inserting the data.
                      df.to_sql(con=engine, name=table_name, if_exists='replace', schema=None)
                  # Close the Excel file.
                  ex_op.close()
```

this piece of code satisfies my req this can be edited to do a lot of other things.